# Would it still TDD if I would plan and list (as comment) all test ahead?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, phpunit, tdd

Would it still count Tdd when I some kind of start planning before even writing test down? I mean create test files with commented test case names. In that way I could for example anticipate and simulate the app ahead, some kind pre plan the tests and at the same time create a plan. I doubt that it would still TDD but I would be happy to get some views on this.

Example:

```
class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    // Authentication Tests
    // ====================
    // guest_can_register_with_valid_data
    // guest_can_register_with_valid_data_and_receive_verification_sms
    // guest_can_register_with_valid_data_and_verify_sms
    // guest_can_register_with_valid_data_and_verify_sms_and_login

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you review Kent Beck's *Test Driven Development by Example*; all of part 1 (seventeen chapters) prominently feature a "checklist" of test ideas, some of which have already been done, others that are deferred to future.

Putting that checklist into your IDE (as opposed to, for example, writing them down on a convenient piece of paper) is *fine*.

But it's also not particularly important; TDD is red/green/refactor; it doesn't constrain the implementation details of the second brain we use to keep track of where we think we are going.